# TFS - dynamic chekin email

Tags: tfs

How to configure TFS check-in email by dynamic user id. 
consider,
 User2 : user1 doing check-in auto email will be user1@domain.com \
like wise
 User1 : user2 doing check-in auto email will be user2@domain.com

.. similar to svn auto email. Is this possible in TFS ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want if you install the Alerts Explorer add-in available as part of the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) VS Extension

Comment: How can I configure for my username@domain.com ? can you please give some details

Comment: How can I configure for my username@domain.com ? can you please give some details